# How to set a Camel property as a List or Array in Spring XML

Tags: xml, spring, apache-camel, spring-dsl

I am developing a simple processor to verify the existence of mandatory properties in a route.
I need to add that list on the route definition before calling the processor.

```
    <route id="test1">
        <from uri="/v1/test1" />
        <setProperty propertyName="mandatoryProperties">
            <simple resultType="java.util.List">${[A,B,C]}</simple>
        </setProperty>
        <bean ref="propertiesProcessor" />
    </route>
```

My Processor is:

```
@Component
public class MandatoryPropertiesProcessor {

@Handler
public void process(final Exchange exchange, final @Properties Map properties, final @ExchangeProperty("mandatoryProperties") List<String> mandatoryProperties) {

    List<String> missingPropertiesList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(mandatoryProperties)) {

        for (String mandatoryProperty : mandatoryProperties) {

            if (!properties.containsKey(mandatoryProperty)) {
                missingPropertiesList.add(mandatoryProperty);
            }
        }
    }

    exchange.setProperty(MISSING_PROPERTIES, missingPropertiesList);
}
```

}

when i try to call this route i get:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleParserException: Unknown function: ["A","B","C"]
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionExpression.createSimpleExpression(SimpleFunctionExpression.java:216)
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionExpression.createExpression(SimpleFunctionExpression.java:40)
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionStart.doCreateLiteralExpression(SimpleFunctionStart.java:58)
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionStart.createExpression(SimpleFunctionStart.java:48)
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionParser.createExpressions(SimpleExpressionParser.java:163)
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SimpleExpressionParser.java:86)
    at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionParser.parseExpression(SimpleExpressionParser.java:53)
```

Is possible to achieve this in XML?

Comment: whay are you using $. Remove that

Comment: @pvpkiran i have removed the $ and now i do not have any errors, but the header does not exist.

Comment: just try this `<simple resultType="java.util.List">A,B,C</simple>`

Comment: That expression still does not work.

Comment: Do you want to have an ArrayList with 3 values: A, B and C. You can use groovy or some more powerful scripting languages to initialize such thing

Comment: @ClausIbsen so it's not possible to do that with simple? unfortunately i am not allowed to add any library.

Comment: You can create a `ArrayList` bean outside Camel using the `<bean>` syntax. Both spring XML and blueprint XML has ways of doing that. Then you can use the ref language to set the bean as an exchange property in the Camel route.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use Spring Framework and the mandatory properties seem to be a static list, right?

If so, just use Spring configuration to create the list or any other collection of mandatory properties and inject it into your `MandatoryPropertiesProcessor` bean. No Camel at all for this part.

If the list changes, only the config and the bean change, but not your Camel route. This is reasonable since the "processing workflow" implemented through your route does not change.

Comment: It seems a good idea but with this solution i cant reuse the processor in another route because each one has different mandatory parameters.

Comment: Why? You can configure multiple instances of the same bean class with Spring and inject them into the corresponding routes.